# JMeter Network Testing

Tags: networking, jmeter, bandwidth

Is it possible to carry out a performance testing such as testing network bandwidths or different networks like some place in Africa does not have the same bandwidth as in NYC , testing their speed without any sort of HTTP requests ?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Long details short: Please check this link http://qainsights.com/simulate-bandwidth-in-jmeter/. Detailed steps https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test.

Answer (score 1):

It is, according to [How to simulate network bandwidth in JMeter?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks) JMeter Wiki page it can be controlled via the following properties:

```
httpclient.socket.http.cps=0
httpclient.socket.https.cps=0
```

Setting them to something above zero will throttle JMeter network traffic to the given value (`cps` == `character per second`)

The properties can be set in 2 ways:

1. Added to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder, JMeter restart will be required to pick them up)
2. Passed via [-J command-line arguments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like

   ```
   jmeter -Jhttpclient.socket.http.cps=1234 -Jhttpclient.socket.https.cps=1234 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

See [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test) if anything remains unclear.